# Jquery slide event to make text with different colors

Tags: jquery

I want to have a jquery slide event making text with different colors inside a loop.
I tried to do so with many but I am not getting the right result.

Here is how I tried :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
//$("p").slideUp("fast");
$("#but").click(function(){


    for ( var i = 0; i < 19; i++ ) {

        var colors = ["#CCCCCC","#333333","#990099"];                
          var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length); 
        $("p").html("<i>This is my <b>HTML</b> data</i>");
        $("p").css({"color":  colors[rand],  "font-        size":"30px"}).slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000);

    }

});

 //$("p").mouseenter(function() { $(this).slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000);}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show it what you have done in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I'm making the text " This is my HTML data" inside a slide event. It's working fine. Now I'm trying to make this text to change color for each iteration. The color property inside css is defined dynamic. But color not changing in each iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 19; i++ ) {
    var colors = ["#CCCCCC","#333333","#990099"];           
    $("p").html("<i>This is my <b>HTML</b> data</i>");
    $("p").css({"font-size":"30px"}).slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000, function(){
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
        $("p").css({"color":  colors[rand]});
    });
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/B5dX8/)